# Enforce type safety in the implementation of a generic method

Tags: java, generics, abstract-class

let's say i have this generic class which does some work and produces a result:

```
public abstract class Work<T> {

    private T mResult;

    public Work(T result) {
        mResult = result;
    }

    public abstract <T> void doWork(T result);

    public T getResult() {
        return mResult;
    }
}
```

For the users of this class i want type safety that would look something like this:

```
Work<MyResult> work = new Work<MyResult>(new MyResult()){
    public void work(MyResult result){
        //...
    }
}
```

The problem is Java doesn't work this way and forces me to cast from the generic type:

```
Work<MyResult> work = new Work<MyResult>(new MyResult()){
    public <T> void work (T result){
        // (MyResult)result - not nice
    }
}
```

Is there a way to have type safety in a nice way like in the first example?

Thanks,
Teo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need the `<T>` in the declaration of `doWork`, because you want to use the T that is declared at the class level - you need

```
public abstract void doWork(T result);
```

The current declaration is the same as

```
public abstract <A> void doWork(A result);
```

it isn't necessarily the same T as the rest of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Work<MyResult> work = new Work<MyResult>(new MyResult()){
    public void work(MyResult result){
      // Do something
    }
}
```

---

Your current design of the `Work` class is a little strange. I'm not sure why your `doWork` method requires a result object as an argument. The abstract class also seems to offer little in the way of functionality (although I appreciate this may be a prototype). Perhaps consider an interface instead:

```
public interface Work<T> {    

    public T doWork();   
}
```